# Configure custom container image LABEL using Cloud Native Build Packs/Paketo.io with spring-boot-maven-plugin for GitHub Container Registry link

Tags: spring-boot, github-actions, spring-boot-maven-plugin, buildpack, github-package-registry

I created a simple Spring Boot application using https://start.spring.io/. Now I want to use Paketo.io / Cloud Native Build Pack support of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to build a container image and push it to the GitHub Container Registry using GitHub Actions.

My `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.jonashackt</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>helloworld</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I successfully managed to create a Docker image using the `mvn spring-boot:build-image` command inside my GitHub Actions workflow. I also successfully [pushed it to the GitHub Container Registry (following this guide)](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2021/03/github-container-registry/). Here's my `build.yml` workflow:

```
name: publish

on: [push]

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up JDK 15
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 15

    - name: Build the hello-world Docker image
      run: |
        echo 'Login to GitHub Container Registry'
        echo $CR_PAT | docker login ghcr.io -u jonashackt --password-stdin

        echo 'Build a container image from our Spring Boot app using Paketo.io / Cloud Native Build Packs'     
        mvn spring-boot:build-image --batch-mode --no-transfer-progress

        echo 'tag Paketo build image to have the right GitHub Container Registry coordinates'
        docker tag helloworld:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ghcr.io/jonashackt/helloworld:latest
        
        docker push ghcr.io/jonashackt/helloworld:latest
      env:
        CR_PAT: ${{ secrets.CR_PAT }}
```

But the Container Registry image isn't linked to the GitHub repository. Since this has to be done with a specific OCI compliant `LABEL` inside the `Dockerfile`:

```
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.source="https://github.com/jonashackt/helloworld"
```

How could one configure this `LABEL` using Cloud Native Build Packs / Paketo together with the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` transparently wraps Paketo.io / Cloud Native Build Packs, the best way is to start in https://paketo.io/docs. There's a [section on how to apply custom labels to application images](https://paketo.io/docs/buildpacks/configuration/#applying-custom-labels):

> Paketo users may add labels to the application image using the Image
> Labels Buildpack.

As `org.opencontainers.image.source` is a OCI-specific label, the [the Image Labels Buildpack](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/image-labels#behavior) will set the correct label for us. All we have to do, is to pass an environment variable to the Paketo build that we prefix with `BP_OCI_`. Have a look at [the possible OCI specific labels in the docs](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/image-labels#behavior). For example, if we run the following Paketo build:

```
pack build spring-boot-buildpack
  --path . \
  --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base \
  --env "BP_OCI_DESCRIPTION=Demo Application"
```

The resulting application image will have a `LABEL` defined with the value `org.opencontainers.image.description Demo Application`. So in order to set `org.opencontainers.image.source` we need to define the environment variable `BP_OCI_SOURCE` for our Paketo build!

But as we use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` here, we need to somehow configure this environment variable inside our `pom.xml`, since we don't directly interact with the Paketo CLI. The [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image-customization) tells us that we can use the `image.env` tags inside a `configuration` tag to define

> Environment variables that should be passed to the builder.

In order to configure the OCI-specific `LABEL org.opencontainers.image.source https://github.com/yourGitHubUserOrOrgaName/yourRepositoryName` to the application image build by Paketo using the spring-boot-maven-plugin, add the following tags to your `pom.xml` (here's also [a fully comprehensible example project](https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-buildpack) including a [pom.xml](https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-buildpack/blob/main/pom.xml)):

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <env>
                            <BP_OCI_SOURCE>https://github.com/yourGitHubUserOrOrgaName/yourRepositoryName</BP_OCI_SOURCE>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Now your image gets linked to your GitHub repository. If you look at your account's packages and click into the build image, you should see all your `README.md` information mapped like this:

[image]