How to add container labels with Spring Boot `build-image`?
In a regular Dockerfile I can add arbitrary metadata labels, for example:
LABEL title="My Spring Boot App"
LABEL version="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
LABEL authors="stewart"

These labels can be later inspected with the command
docker inspect --format='{{json .Config.Labels}}' my-spring-boot-image:latest

How can one achieve the same thing, if you are creating your Docker image using the spring-boot-maven-plugin ?
mvn spring-boot:build-image


To the ghost: Hit-n-Run downvotes are, frankly, unhelpful.

Maybe something useful in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66585032/14072498

@RoarS. This is indeed what I was looking for. I will try out that answer, and if successful, I will mark this question as a duplicate of that one.
